# Error getting offset for partition after upgrading kafka from version 2.3.0 to 3.3.1

Tags: apache-kafka

ERROR [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Error getting offset for partition Prd_IN_AlertsPublish-28 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)

Answer (score 0):

error resolved after whitelisting kafka topic

**kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --whitelist '.*'**